# SQL Auto Increment ID

Tags: php, sql, tags

I have an SQL table with an auto-increment field. I know people have asked how to retrieve the ID of the 'last entry' after the insert has taken place, and I know how to do that. What I want to do is duplicate the auto-generated field in to a second column of the same table - how do I modify my insert code to do this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tags` (`tid`,`tagid`,`tagname`) VALUES('','INSERTED.ID','{$tagname}')");
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to make two rows equal each other. I.E. if two different tags (with different unique ids) have the same tagid, then I can use the 'tagid' reference elsewhere as a unique identifier and cycle through them. I can also retain knowledge of which tag is the parent tag - because it will have the same 'tid' as 'tagid'.

I have a system for tagging events; but sometimes I miss-spell a tag... so rather than correcting all the mistakes, I want to make my system error proof by allowing miss-spelt tags to be joined up and treated the same way as a the correct tag.

Would appreciate your help - even if that means doing this a completely different way.

Thanks,

Comment: this is an anti-pattern.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1) You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) mysql function, but in a second query, not in the same.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

2) Define a insert [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) in the table, then when you insert, the trigger "triggers" and do the action in the trigger.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tag_tid BEFORE INSERT ON tags
 FOR EACH ROW NEW.tid = NEW.id;
```

Note: Short creator, see more in the link.

Comment: Very nice. I will try the trigger. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've decided to do 2 separate queries in case I ever get confused by the trigger being hidden outwith my code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to alter the table to set the field to autoincrement. And then I believe when you insert anything it increments. There is also this statement called on duplicate...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: So my column a - TID is an auto-increment field and a primary key. I can only specify one primary key, so what I want to do is make the primary key repeat in the 'tagid' field... I'm reading the on duplicate section through now!

Comment: you cannot have the primary key repeat. Its what makes each row unique and sql will not accept it. If you want you could create a different field and make it not the primary key. Then you could have duplicates. There are also these things called aggregate functions. The one that will probably help you is Max() this will get the max of some column. You would probably store that in a variable and use it in your queries. Here is the linkhttp://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could store the previous id, and then use it in your query string.

```
$previous_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tags` (`tid`,`tagid`,`tagname`) VALUES('','$previous_id','{$tagname}')");
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Most of the time this is a single isolated query so I'm not necessarily cycling through and creating a past id to capture... Is the mysql_insert_id always the same as the next auto-increment value? :)